# Why v-model is not working?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

This is my very first code in Vue.js. I am following a simple online tutorial. After installing the application using the vue-cli, I created a simple component
`Test.vue` which contains a simple input control bound to the message property of my model:

> Test.vue

```
<template>
  <div 
    <input 
        type="text" 
        v-model="message"/>
    <br/>
    <p>The value of the input is: {{ message }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {  
      data:{
        message: 'My name'
      }
    };
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Then I load this component inside the `<App />`. But when I write a text inside the input box, the `<p>` element is not updated...

[image]

What am I doing wrong? This looks pretty straightforward. Thanks you for your suggestions and pointing me to the right direction.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In a component, [data must be a function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function).

```
export default {  
  data(){
    return {
      message: 'My name'
    }
  }
};
```

Also, your template is missing a `>` in the first div, but I'm guessing that happened writing the question.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input 
        type="text" 
        v-model="message"/>
    <br/>
    <p>The value of the input is: {{ message }}</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. the first <div was a typo. Is data as a function a feature of vue.js v2? because in my tutorial data is just a json object

Comment: @TheSoul Data must be a function for *components*. A root Vue instance it can be an object.

Comment: This answer was honestly too difficult of an answer to find. Copy and paste verbatim from Vue Docs and tutorials, and nothing. Was really irritating me. Thanks!!